# Binding List<string> property to DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF project in which I wanted to display some data in a Datagrid. I have a class which is given below.

```
   public class Demo
   {
       public string ColunmHeader{ get; set; } 
       private List<string> values = new List<string>();
   }
```

I have List which I need to bind to Datagrid columns. The ColunmHeader property should be the name of datagrid column and the List of values should be shown under the column header. How can I bind the List Values to datagrid columns?

Comment: Do you want to display `values` in a single column?

Comment: Yes.For each ColumHeader values will be visible under this.

Comment: So, why do you need a `DataGrid` with a single column? Why don't display `values` in a `ListBox`?

Comment: Actually I need a dynamic datagrid which will generate the columns according to the List<Demo>. something like this.   
var data =new  List<Demo>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
            {
                {
                    DataGrd.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = data[i].Name });
                }

         }

Comment: Please, add your .xaml code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a list of "models" to the datagrid.

e.g.

```
public class Example
{
     public String Value { get; set;}

}


List<Example> list = new List<Example>():
```

The column headers will be the name of the property.